# Accept vs Agree

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

In a contract, is there a difference between "accepting the terms and conditions" versus "agreeing to the terms and conditions"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Agree*** and ***accept*** are equivalent terms in this context.

Answer (score 4):

No. It is semantics. The signature on the contract is what represents a willingness to adhere to all requisite duties and rights that the contract puts upon each party to the instrument.